# How to add dynamic number of rows on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have my markup like this

```
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" data-id="3">3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-id="2">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-id="5">5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-id="7">7</a></li>
    </ul>
    <table id="data">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="name" class="name"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="email" class="email"></td>
    </tr>   
    </table>
```

Now I want that when I will make click on the a tag which data-id is 3 it should add 3 rows to the table. If I make click on another a tag with `data-id` 7 then it should add 7 rows to the table. The first row will be the same for each new action. I mean

```
<tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Email</th>
</tr>
```

will be constant for the table the rest rows will be added with Name and Email input fields. For that I have made my jQuery like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('table#data tr:last').hide();
        $('body').on('click', 'li a', function(event) {
            var Parent = $('table#data tr:last');
            event.preventDefault();
            var Number = $(this).attr('data-id');
            console.log(Number);
            for ( i=0; i<Number; i++ ) {
                $(Parent).insertAfter(Parent);
            }
        });
    })

    </script>
```

But its not working. I have created the fiddle for [this](http://jsfiddle.net/NewUserFiddle/dgkup38d/). So can someone kindly tell me how to do this? Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable. Thanks

**Edit**

I want that when I click on 7 it should add 7 rows so only 7 rows will be seen.But when I again click on 2 rows it should only show 2 rows and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('table#data tr:last').hide();
    $('body').on('click', 'li a', function(event) {
        $('table#data').find('tr.row').remove();
        var Parent = $('table#data tr:last');
        event.preventDefault();
        var Number = $(this).attr('data-id');
        alert(Number);        
        for ( i=0; i<Number; i++ ) {
            $('<tr class="row"><td>Hi</td></tr>').insertAfter(Parent);
        }
    });
})
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/Ldrsm2cs/2/

Comment: Thanks for the answer but can you see when I click on lets say 2 it adds two rows and when I again make click on 7 it adds another 7 rows so the total rows is 9. I want only 7 when 7 is clicked and only 2 rows when 2 is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

1) Your element is `hidden`, you should make it `visible`.
2) You should **copy** your element.
3) You should remove old rows.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('table#data tr:last').hide();
    $('body').on('click', 'li a', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var count = $(this).attr('data-id');

        // remove old rows
        $('table#data tr + tr:not(:last)').remove();

        var $node = $('table#data tr:last');
        for ( i=0; i < count; i++ ) {
            $node.clone().show().insertBefore($node);
        }
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dgkup38d/8/).

Comment: update your fiddle.. So that it will help for others

Comment: but when I am adding new rows why the first row (Name, Email heading) is removing? I want them constant in each addition of rows..

Answer (score 0):

You are moving that last row over and over again. Either get its html content as text, or clone it in your loop:

```
...
Parent.clone().show().insertAfter(Parent);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" data-id="3">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-id="2">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-id="5">5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-id="7">7</a></li>
</ul>
<table id="data">
<tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Email</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="name" class="name" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="email" class="email" /></td>
</tr>   
</table>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
          $('table#data tr:eq(1)').hide();          
          $('ul').on('click', 'li a', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var Parent = $('table#data tr:eq(1)');
            $('table#data tr:not(:hidden)').remove();
            var Number = $(this).data('id');
            for ( i=0; i< Number; i++ ) {
                Parent.clone().show().insertAfter(Parent);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

While you already have other answers, I thought I'd suggest the following approach:

```js
$('[data-id]').on('click', function(e){
  // preventing any default click actions (page-reloads, hash-changes, etc):
  e.preventDefault();
  
  // caching 'this' (in case of further use):
  var self = this,
      // using native DOM approaches to retrieving the text, rather
      // than using jQuery to perform a simple task:
      textProp = 'textContent' in document ? 'textContent' : 'innerText',
      // finding how many rows we want:
      howMany = parseInt(self[textProp].trim(), 10),
      // retrieving the 'template' row:
      source = $('tbody.template tr'),
      // where we're working on the content:
      content = $('#content'),
      // finding the children already present (if any):
      contentChildren = content.children(),
      // finding how many children (if any) are already present:
      contentChildrenLength = contentChildren.length;
  
  // basically, 'do we need to *add* content:
  if (contentChildrenLength === 0 || contentChildrenLength < howMany) {
    // len is the amount we need to add, if there are zero children we add
    // the full amount requested; otherwise we work out the difference between
    // already-existing content and the number we want, and then add that
    // difference:
    for (var i = 0, len = contentChildrenLength === 0 ? howMany : howMany - contentChildrenLength; i < len; i++) {
      content.append(source.clone(true, true));
    }
  }
  // if we already have the required number of children we just quit:
  else if (contentChildrenLength === howMany) {
    return false;
  }
  // if we have more elements already than we (now) want, we remove
  // the excess:
  else if (contentChildrenLength > howMany) {
    content.children().slice(howMany).remove();
  }
});
```

```css
tbody.template {
  visibility: collapse;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" data-id="2">2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-id="3">3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-id="5">5</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-id="7">7</a></li>
</ul>
<table id="data">
  <thead>
   <tr>
     <th>Name</th>
     <th>Email</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <!-- creating a (css-hidden) 'template' row -->
  <tbody class="template">
   <tr>
        <!-- appended '[]' to the input elements' names (on the assumption you're
             sending this to a server, this is optional (adjust to taste)-->
     <td><input type="text" name="name[]" class="name" /></td>
     <td><input type="text" name="email[]" class="email" /></td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
  <!-- this is where the content will be appended -->
  <tbody id="content"></tbody>
</table>
```

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [Conditional (`assessment ? ifTrue : ifFalse;`) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).
  - [`event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault).
  - [`property in objectName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in).
- jQuery:

  - [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/).
  - [`children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/).
  - [`clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/).
  - [has-attribute (`[attribute]`) selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/).
  - [`remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/).
  - [`slice()`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the jQuery library: [relCopy](http://www.andresvidal.com/labs/relcopy.html)

It'll help you easily clone/remove row of fields (or anything else).